# Изменение размера виджета пользователем

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, qsizegrip

Можно ли каким-либо способом сделать изменение размера `QWidget` пользователем. То есть с помощью растягивания мышью.

Update:  изменение размера `QWidget` нужно сделать со всех сторон.

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class DragButton(QPushButton):

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.__mousePressPos = None
        self.__mouseMovePos = None
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.__mousePressPos = event.globalPos()
            self.__mouseMovePos = event.globalPos()

        super(DragButton, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            currPos = self.mapToGlobal(self.pos())
            globalPos = event.globalPos()
            diff = globalPos - self.__mouseMovePos
            newPos = self.mapFromGlobal(currPos + diff)
            self.move(newPos)

            self.__mouseMovePos = globalPos

        super(DragButton, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if self.__mousePressPos is not None:
            moved = event.globalPos() - self.__mousePressPos
            if moved.manhattanLength() > 3:
                event.ignore()
                return

        super(DragButton, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    w = QWidget()
    w.resize(800,600)

    button = DragButton("Drag", w)

    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

И как суда изменение размера вставить?

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте код, который вы уже написали.

Comment: отвечает ли https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1339117 на ваш вопрос ?

Comment: Да отвечает, но это можно сделать со всех сторон.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я обновил свой ответ [**Есть ли виджеты в PyQt5, размер которых может изменять пользователь?**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1339117/%D0%95%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-pyqt5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C) с учетом ваших пожеланий, попробуйте.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class SizeGrip(QtWidgets.QSizeGrip):
    def __init__(self, location_angle, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        parent.installEventFilter(self)
        self.setFixedSize(30, 30)
        self.location_angle = location_angle
 
        if self.location_angle == 'left_top':        
            self.polygon = QtGui.QPolygon([
                QtCore.QPoint(10, 20), 
                QtCore.QPoint(20, 10), 
                QtCore.QPoint(10, 10), 
            ]) 
        elif self.location_angle == 'right_top':        
            self.polygon = QtGui.QPolygon([
                QtCore.QPoint(20, 10), 
                QtCore.QPoint(20, 20), 
                QtCore.QPoint(10, 10), 
            ])             
        elif self.location_angle == 'left_bottom':        
            self.polygon = QtGui.QPolygon([
                QtCore.QPoint(10, 20), 
                QtCore.QPoint(20, 20), 
                QtCore.QPoint(10, 10), 
            ])            
        elif self.location_angle == 'right_bottom':
            self.polygon = QtGui.QPolygon([
                QtCore.QPoint(10, 20), 
                QtCore.QPoint(20, 10), 
                QtCore.QPoint(20, 20), 
            ])

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Resize:
            if self.location_angle == 'left_top': 
                geo = QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 30, 30)
                self.setGeometry(geo)
            elif self.location_angle == 'right_top': 
                _geo = self.rect()
                _geo.moveBottomRight(source.rect().bottomRight())
                x = _geo.x()
                geo = QtCore.QRect(x, 0, 30, 30)
                self.setGeometry(geo)
            elif self.location_angle == 'left_bottom': 
                _geo = self.rect()
                _geo.moveBottomRight(source.rect().bottomRight())
                y = _geo.y()
                geo = QtCore.QRect(0, y, 30, 30)
                self.setGeometry(geo)
            elif self.location_angle == 'right_bottom':
                geo = self.rect()
                geo.moveBottomRight(source.rect().bottomRight())
                self.setGeometry(geo)
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        qp.setPen(QtCore.Qt.white)
        qp.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.red)         
        qp.drawPolygon(self.polygon)


class Container(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.sizeGrip1 = SizeGrip('left_top', self)
        self.sizeGrip2 = SizeGrip('right_top', self)        
        self.sizeGrip3 = SizeGrip('left_bottom', self)
        self.sizeGrip4 = SizeGrip('right_bottom', self)
        
        self.startPos = None
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(20, 20, 20, 20)
        self.setStyleSheet('''
            Container {
                background: lightblue;
                border: 0px;
                border-radius: 4px;
            }
        ''')

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.startPos = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.startPos:
            self.move(self.pos() + (event.pos() - self.startPos))

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.startPos = None


class GraphicsRoundedFrame(QtWidgets.QGraphicsProxyWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.container = Container()
        self.setWidget(self.container)

    def addWidget(self, widget):
        self.container.layout().addWidget(widget)

    def paint(self, qp, opt, widget):
        qp.save()
        p = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        p.addRoundedRect(self.boundingRect().adjusted(0, 0, -.5, -.5), 4, 4)
        qp.setClipPath(p)
        super().paint(qp, opt, widget)
        qp.restore()


class View(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        self.setScene(scene)
        self.setRenderHints(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 1024, 768)

        texture = QtGui.QImage(30, 30, QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32)
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(texture)
        qp.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.white)
        qp.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(189, 190, 191), 2))
        qp.drawRect(texture.rect())
        qp.end()
        scene.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(texture))

        testFrame = GraphicsRoundedFrame()
        scene.addItem(testFrame)
        testFrame.container.layout().addStretch(1)
        
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("lena.jpg").scaled(100, 100))
        testFrame.addWidget(self.label_2)
        testFrame.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel(
            'lena.jpg', alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter))
        testFrame.container.layout().addStretch(1)
        
        testFrame.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton('I am a button'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = View()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]